# Why doesn't rustup update rustc as I expected?

Tags: rust

It looks like it has updated to 1.64.0, which is what I want, but then when I check the version, the update did not happen.

```
root@c1:~# rustup update 
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: checking for self-updates

  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)

info: cleaning up downloads & tmp directories

root@c1:~# rustc --version
rustc 1.58.0-nightly (072799443 2021-11-06)
```

Comment: Also run `which rustc` and `rustup show` and [edit] that output into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because rustup updated a different rust installation than the one you checked its version using rustc --version.
you can see that rustup has updated a stable version of rust while rustc is nightly, as the 1st comment said.  run which rustc and rustup show to locate both installations and then fix your paths accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why and how, but for me the issue was fixed by running: `rustup self uninstall`, and then reinstalling using whatever way suites your operating system. Documented here: https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install.